# Keep Scroll-y after re-render in React/Redux

Tags: reactjs, scroll, scrollbar

I have a calendar component and there is an hour-picker inside that has *scroll-y: auto*.
Every time user clicks on *hour button*, information goes to Redux, so the component is re-rendered. 
The only problem I have is that the scroll is moving to the top and I want it to be at the same place where the user picked the hour. I tried to save the scroll position in LocalStorage but I can't figure out how to set scroll position after re-rendering.

```
saveTimeInStorage = () => {
   let el = document.querySelector('.list-group');
   localStorage.setItem('scroll', el.scrollTop);
}

chooseTime = (time) => {
   this.saveTimeInStorage();
   this.props.setTime(time);
  }

render() {

return (
<div className="wrapper">
   <div className="calendar">
      <div className="calendar__picture"></div>
      <div className="calendar-header">
         <h3>  Выберите дату и время</h3>
      </div>
      <div className="day-time">
      <DatePicker
        selected={this.props.date}
        locale="ru"
        onChange={(day) => {this.props.setDate(day)}}
        inline />

         <div className="time">
            <div className="list-group hour">
               {this.hours.map(time => (
               <ListGroup.Item
                  id={time}
                  as="li"
                  active={time===this.props.time}
                  onClick={() => this.chooseTime(time)}
                  style={{ textAlign: "right", cursor: "pointer" }} >
                  {time + ":00"}
               </ListGroup.Item>
               ))}
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
```